# Parsing data using NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData() but cannot access Array groups only strings

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, nsjsonserialization

I've downloaded the data below which is in Json format.

```
{"name":"Shropshire Outage","nc_lead":"John Smith","dma":"11/111","username":"vwaghx1","status":"REOPENED","sapOrder":"12341245","ccsText":"123","nbPropAtRisk":12,"logs":[{"dateTime":"2016-04-07 20:02:42","valveStatusChangeDateTime":"2016-04-07 20:02:00","user":"vwaghx1","uid":null,"task":"CUSTPOORSUPPLIES","id_log":1489},{"dateTime":"2016-04-07 20:03:35","valveStatusChangeDateTime":"2016-04-07 20:02:00","user":"vwaghx1","uid":1238768765,"task":"PRESSURELOGGER","id_log":1490},{"dateTime":"2016-04-07 20:04:36","valveStatusChangeDateTime":"2016-04-07 20:02:00","user":"vwaghx1","uid":7692466478,"task":"CUSTSUPPLIESRESTOREDSOME","id_log":1491}],"id_event":601,"region":"Shropshire","trigger":"No Supply Call”,”valveOps":[{"dateTime":"2016-04-07 20:06:12","user":"vwaghx1","uid":7866756788,"x":678666,"y":723325,"description”:”Burst main downstream valve","id_valve_op":523},{"dateTime":"2016-04-07 20:05:31","user":"vwaghx1","uid":5674456470,"x":344534,"y":723433,"description":"Valve to separate both rezones","id_valve_op":522},{"dateTime":"2016-04-14 12:32:00","user":"vwaghx1","uid":1234512345,"x":123123,"y":123123,"description":"test","id_valve_op":541}],"images":[{"name":"After improvement.jpg","dateTimeCreated":"2016-04-08 14:10:30","contentType":"image/jpeg","caption":null,"uuid":null,"fileExtension":"jpeg","id_image":661},...]}
```

However, when I try to parse it using the code below, I can only access the string values such as "name","nc_lead", "region" etc.

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
    for item in json {
        if let dict = item as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let nameStr = dict["name"] as? String {
                incidentList.valueStr = nameStr
            }
            if let codeStr = dict["dma"] as? String {
                incidentList.valueStr = codeStr
            }
            if let region = dict[“region”] as? String {
                incidentList.valueStr = region
            }
            if let ncLead = dict[“nc_lead”] as? String {
                incidentList.valueStr = ncLead
            }
```

I need to access the group values like "logs", "images" and "valveOps", which have their own string values in arrays.
How can I change my code so that I can access the strings as I am now and also load the groups into arrays?

Comment: Same idea you're already using but adapt to the JSON structure. Like `item["valveOps"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]` (array of dictionaries), and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this way, declare 3 array first.

```
var logArr: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()
var imageArr: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()
var valveArr: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()
```

Now use this array where you are getting response

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
for item in json {
    if let dict = item as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        if let nameStr = dict["name"] as? String {
            incidentList.valueStr = nameStr
        }
        if let codeStr = dict["dma"] as? String {
            incidentList.valueStr = codeStr
        }
        if let region = dict["region"] as? String {
            incidentList.valueStr = region
        }
        if let ncLead = dict["nc_lead"] as? String {
            incidentList.valueStr = ncLead
        }
        if let logs = dict["logs"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            self.logArr = logs
        }
        if let valveOps = dict["valveOps"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            self.valveArr = valveOps
        }
        if let images = dict["images"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            self.imageArr = images
        }
```